# local and global variable concept in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python programming. I have some implementation problem with local and global variable concept. I have read some answers about the global and local variables. I tried to use this concept, however, in the code below, I did not get proper output. When I press 'y' it shows the number of the persons in the room 0.

my code:

```
sw1 = 0
sw2 = 0
d1sen1 = 1
d1sen2 = 0
d2sen1 = 1
d2sen2 = 0
chk = 0 
d = 0
count = 0
def dgopenig_operation(x):
    d1sen1 = 0
    d1sen2 = 0
    d2sen1 = 0
    d2sen2 = 0
    print ("the door is going to open")
def doppened_operation():
    d1sen1 = 0
    d1sen2 = 1
    d2sen1 = 0
    d2sen2 = 1
    print ("the door is oppened u can pass now")    
def dgclose_operation(x):
    d1sen1 = 0
    d1sen2 = 0
    d2sen1 = 0
    d2sen2 = 0
    print ("the door  is  going to closed")   
def close_operation():
    d1sen1 = 0
    d1sen2 = 0
    d2sen1 = 0
    d2sen2 = 0
    print ("the door is going to closed") 
sw1 = input("enter 1 for enteringing the room")
dgopenig_operation(sw1)
doppened_operation()
chk = input("are u passed or not? y/n")
if (chk == 'y' and sw1 == 1):
    dgclose_operation(1)
    global count
    count = count +1    
else:
    print ('the door is still oppening')

print( 'the no of person  in the room is ',count)
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Java or the Oracle 11g Database? Tag soup = down-voted.

Comment: I removed the redundant tags. Please take care to tag appropriately, in order to get your question in front of the right people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have almost done. But there is a small mistake in if condition. Your required condition should be like below:

```
if (chk == 'y' and sw1 == '1'):
```

That means you should keep 1 in single quotes '1' because it's a string

Comment: first  thanks for solution. i used global key word in my code.  it gives an warning  that SyntaxWarning: name 'count' is assigned to before global declaration

Comment: can you please paste code as a comment ? By that I can understand ur exact problem.